# Use of the word "farewell"

Tags: nouns, exclamations

If I use "farewell to headache" as a slogan, would it imply a statement similar to "relieves headache" or "treats headache"? or is there a contradiction in meaning that headache is a bad thing and you cannot say "good"-bye (i.e. farewell) to a bad thing which you're trying to get rid of (i.e. headache)?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not illogical, nor would it likely be misunderstood.  Using "farewell" in the sense of being rid of a bad thing is not common but is done.

Comment: "Say ''Farewell' to headaches" or "Say 'Farewell' to a headache". Headache is a count noun

Comment: "farewell" is outdated and sounds limper. "goodbye" sounds stronger, (and it has been around long enough in its current form to have lost its original sense of _God be with ye_.)    http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=good-bye

Answer (score 0):

It'a a formulaic word to indicate a departure.  It no more means that you wish the headache a good time after it leaves, than you hold dear those whom you address that way in the salutation to a business letter: "Dear sir."

Answer (score -1):

I think 'farewell' is too kind a word. You don't want to express your good wishes to a headache.

I suppose it could be seen as irony, for example as in: "Have a nice day headache!"

"Say goodbye to headaches (or whatever other ailment" is already an over-used catchphrase. I don't think 'farewell' is sufficiently different to make an impact.

Answer (score -2):

Last week I was watching Romeo and Juliet. But lets go straight, if you read the book you would note the change of a few word, one of those words is farewell, it means good bye or later on. 
I give a sentence so you can understand better. 
I hate farewells, they make cry. 
There's the word and how I'd use nowadays. Back in the 1900s they would say
"hey, good to see you."
"good to see you too."
"See you later."
 "Farewell"
So if you say "farewell to a headache", then you are saying good bye, i dont want you to interrupt my life again. 
Thats what i think it means, i hope it helps you.